# Run Apriori algorithm in python 2.7

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, association-rules

I have a DataFrame in python by using pandas which has 3 columns and 80.000.000 rows.

The Columns are: {event_id,device_id,category}.[[image: here is the first 5 rows of my df]]

each device has many events and each event can have more than one category.

I want to run Apriori algorithm to find out which categories seem together.

My idea is to create a list of lists[[]]: to save the categories which are in the same event for each device. like: [('a'),('a','b')('d'),('s','a','b')] then giving the list of lists as transactions to the algorithm. I need help to create the list of lists.

If you have better idea please tell me because I am new in Python and this was the only way I found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('device_id')['category'].apply(list).tolist()
```

There's your transactions LOL.

If you aren't limited to Python 2.7, I'd suggest [Orange3-Associate](https://pypi.org/project/Orange3-Associate/) which contains a [frequent_itemsets() function](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html#fpgrowth.frequent_itemsets) based on [FP-growth algorithm](http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/pdf/dami04_fptree.pdf), which is *orders of magnitude* faster than Apriori.

Comment: Your code does not consider the events. For example, device_id=4 has 3 different events.I wand this 3 different events as 3 different transactions.  I should use python, I can not move to Orange.

Comment: In that case, `df.groupby(['device_id', 'event_id'])...` will group by unique device-event combinations. And Orange3-Associate _is_ a Python package. But if it's for homework, you may need to code it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. can you tell me how can I give this list of lists to Orange?

Comment: Please [RTFM](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html#fpgrowth.frequent_itemsets).